# How do you define a "thispage" macro that only works on a particular page?

Tags: macros, page-breaking, page, badness

Sometimes I use `\vbadness=10000` to suppress the warning

```
Underfull \vbox (badness ...) has occurred while \output is active...
```

I put `\vbadness=10000` in the page the warning occurs and `\vbadness=1000` in the next one. I do the same for `\hbadness`.

I know this only removes the warning from the log and doesn't fix anything, but when I can't fix the page where the problem occurs, I just make the warning disappear so it doesn't bother me anymore (I'm a professional typesetter and I'm not allowed to change the text and/or layout to my liking, so sometimes this is the last chance to get rid of that warning).

I know I could use `\vbadness=10000` after `\begin{document}` and `\vbadness=1000` before `\end{document}` to get rid of all those warnings once and for all, but I'd prefer to suppress them one by one in case the authors ask for more changes that might mess up the layout and cause more warnings of that kind (it happens).

To save time it would be very useful to have a macro that changes `\vbadness` only where it's needed. Something like this:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\thispagevbadness

Time's up! Three bucks off!
```

It's possible to do this? I'm sorry not to post any attempts, but I wouldn't know where to start to do this.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to not create bad pages in the first place?  Just add \vfill somewhere between the top and bottom.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Sure, but I work on sources written by other people and not being allowed to edit the text as I please, sometimes bad pages are inevitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really can't recommend this, but has two underfull pages, you can uncomment or comment the page number tests to see or not see either warning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{%
\global\vbadness=1000
% page before the issue
\ifnum\value{page}=1 \global\vbadness=10000 \fi
\ifnum\value{page}=2 \global\vbadness=10000 \fi
}
\flushbottom

\begin{document}

aaa

bbb

\newpage

ccc

ddd

\pagebreak

eee

fff

\pagebreak

ggg
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This suppress the badness on page two. But it is a bit fishy that one has to do a global assignment.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

1.\rule{1cm}{0.42\textheight}

\rule{1cm}{0.572\textheight}


2.\rule{1cm}{0.42\textheight} 

\AddToHookNext{shipout/before}{%
 \global\vbadness=10000 %set
 \AddToHookNext{shipout/before}{\global\vbadness=1000}%reset
 }  

\rule{1cm}{0.572\textheight}

3.\rule{1cm}{0.42\textheight}

\rule{1cm}{0.572\textheight}

4.\rule{1cm}{0.42\textheight}

\rule{1cm}{0.572\textheight}

\end{document}
```